# React Router Redirect overriding other router components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to achieve the following path structure

```
/ -> /home
/home -> /home/dashboard
```

Now when coming from "/" as the path, that works properly, with the Dashboard component mounting exactly once. When navigating directly to "/home" the redirect to "/home/dashboard" is, as far as I understand it, overridden by the redirect to "/home" and thus, no dashboard rendering.

A second problem is that when going directly to "/home/dashboard", the Dashboard component is rendered twice, resulting in an async call going into the void from the first render and causing the typical "potential memory leak" warning.

The components:

app.js;

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path='/' component={Root}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

root.js

```
function Root(props) {
    let isLoggedIn;

    const renderHome = () =>{
        console.log("render home redirect") // debug only
        return <Redirect exact from={"/"} to={"/home"}/>
    }
    isLoggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem("token")
    return <>
        <Switch>
            <Route path={"/welcome"} component={Welcome}/>
            {isLoggedIn &&
            <Route path={"/home"} component={Home}/>
            }
            {(isLoggedIn &&
                renderHome()
            ) ||
            <Redirect from={`${props.match.url}/`} to={"/welcome"}/>
            }
        </Switch>
    </>
}
```

home.js

```
function Home(props) {
    return <Switch>
        <Route path={`/home/dashboard`} component={Dashboard}/>
        <Redirect from="/home" to="/home/dashboard"/>
    </Switch>
}
```

dashboard.js

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    state = {
    users: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getUserList().then(value =>
            this.setState({users: value})
        )
    }

    render() {
        console.log("dashbaord render")
        const {users} = this.state
        return (<>
            <div>
                UserList
            </div>
        </>
        );
    }
}
```

When I remove the redirect from "/" to "/home", the direct access to "/home/dashboard" does not cause the memory leak warning and the redirect from "/home" to "/home/dashboard" works, but obviously there is no redirect from "/" to "/home" then.

What mistake am I making with the redirects?

Comment: It seems like: `/ -> /home` + `/home -> /home/dashboard` = `/ -> /home/dashboard`.

Comment: @AjeetShah That does work, but why is the behaviour in my post described a thing?

Comment: I see two problems: 1. Your rouitng seems unnecessarily complex. 2. You are using `exact` insufficiently. An old post; Have you fixed / solved  your problem?

Comment: Addition to that, there are ways to prevent memory leak without touching **rouitng** setup, by using `isMounted`, a mutable value using `useRef` hook.

Comment: @AjeetShah The routing does seem "unnecessarily complex", because it's the bare minimum to show the problem. There are more routes in my project. Applying your suggestion of the redirect going to the correct component did fix the problem, although i wouldn't consider that a great solution.